# DB2 SQL. Using a Case Statement on an Order By Clause with an alpha and numeric field

Tags: sql, db2, case, sql-order-by

I am attempting to use a case statement in my order by clause but am unsuccessful because one field is char and one field is numeric. If I put a Char() around the numeric, I don't get the sort I need because it is three byte numeric, 1, 2, 3. Which sorts in char() like 1, 10, 100, 2, etc
Is there a way to pad with zeros so that it sorts properly?
Code:

```
Order by                                  
  Case                                    
     When :SortBy = 'I' then LProd    <-- Char
     When :SortBy = 'L' then Char(LLine)  <-- Numeric
  End;
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try `DIGITS()`

```
Order by                                  
  Case                                    
     When :SortBy = 'I' then LProd    <-- Char
     When :SortBy = 'L' then digits(LLine)  <-- Numeric
  End;
```

Comment: Nice : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=359d4d4c6753853662913bb1a4cd0db9

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte(common table expression) to first order by LProd and give it a rank(numeric value). And then select from that cte and order with what ever you need because both will be numeric.

```
with cte as(select id, rank() over (order by LProd) as LProd_ord, LProd, LLine from test)
select id, LProd, LLine
from cte
order by Case                                    
     When 'I' = 'I' then LProd_ord    
     When 'I' = 'L' then LLine
  End ;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=333d466d0a88037dbff0d8965bc2c994)